# How can I select an object on right mouse button's "contextmenu" event

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to add a custom context menu on right mouse button click, so user could delete an object.

I already managed to get access to the "contextmenu" event, but to fire removeObject function I have to make the object active.

```
const upperCanvas = document.getElementsByClassName("upper-canvas")[0];

upperCanvas.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    canvas.selection = true;
});
```

I was trying to call canvas.fire('mouse:click') afterwards but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `fireRightClick: true` for canvas instance and in mouse up event check for button value 3, which is for right click. And then remove the target using `canvas.remove(object)`.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  stopContextMenu: true,
  fireRightClick: true
});
var textbox = new fabric.Textbox('FABRICJS')
canvas.add(textbox)
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(options) {
  if (options.button == 3) {
    canvas.remove(options.target);
  }
})
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.6.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width=400 height=400></canvas>
```